# I cannot access my Div from the Code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, code-behind

I do not manage to access a div element from code behind in ASP.NET:

Inside my aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ContactForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="Form_Mailer_ContactForm" %>
...
<div  runat="server" id="SentFormDiv">
    <s>my content</s>
</div>
```

Inside the corresponding .cs file (ContactForm.aspx):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    this.SentFormDiv.Visible=false; 
}
```

I get the usual compilation error message:

> does not contain a definition for 'SentFormDiv' and no extension
>   method 'SentFormDiv' accepting a first argument of type
>   'xxx.SentFormDiv' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

The odd part is that is I start typing `SentFor` into the code behind, the Intellisense does suggest me `SentFormDiv`!!

What did I miss?

Comment: Try give it a name attribute.

Comment: @PauloJunior That has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I guess your `Div` is inside another control and if so you need to use the `FindControl`. Like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/40025036/2946329

Comment: @ S.Akbari : was a good idea but it is not my problem.
My div was not inside an asp control.
Plus, if I make the same test with another dif that I place right after the <body> tag, the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please reference this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316757/cant-access-control-id-in-code-behind) question for help. Without seeing your full code, there is no way to give you a definitive answer. Also, as an aside, `this.SentFormDiv` can be simplified to `SentFormDiv`.

Comment: Yeaaah! :)
One of the suggestions from this post made the trick.
That was not the main answer but this one:

Problem is you might have multiple aspx files with codefile in page directive points to same codebehind file. It expects the same control to exists in all the aspx file linked to same code behind and thus throwing compilation error.

Thx a ton Ethilium!

Comment: Glad to help A.D. I've run into this issue myself (as I'm sure many have as well).